# How can I eliminate sequences of numbers from displaying unless in a certain condition?

Tags: c, primes

I am currently in an intro to C class. My instructor tasked me with writing a program that finds and displays all prime numbers from 11 to 999. That was easy. Now he wants me to have the program only display prime quadruples in the same range(they are (11, 13, 17, 19), (101, 103, 107, 109), (191, 193, 197, 199), and (821, 823, 827, 829)). I understand how I could get it to just check and display those four groups KNOWING what they are, but I can't think of what condition to write it for to search for those specific groups. My current program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y, PRIME, MAX=999, MIN=011;

    printf("Prime Quadruples\n");

    for(y=MIN+1; y<MAX; y++)
    {
        PRIME = 1;
        for(x=2; x<y; x++)
            if(y%x == 0)
        {
            PRIME = 0;
            break;
        }
        if(PRIME)
            printf("\n%d", y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of printing them, store them in an array (and update an index). When your index reaches 4, print the data. When the number you are evaluating is a multiple of 10, clear the array (put the index to 0

Comment: In short, you do not "eliminate" sequences but verify, before printing, that you have found the complete sequence that you are looking for.

Comment: I understand, I guess what I mean is that I can't think of what condition would verify the second placeholding value to be the same for four consecutive numbers, and only print if the second value is the same four values in a row.

Comment: Divide them by 10, and print iff all four match after that.

Answer (score 1):

**Prerequisite:**

A Prime Quadruple (also called Prime Quadruplet) is a set of four consecutive prime numbers which are of the form {p, p+2, p+6, p+8}.

The prime quadruples are {5, 7, 11, 13}, {11, 13, 17, 19}, {101, 103, 107, 109}, {191, 193, 197, 199}, {821, 823, 827, 829}, {1481, 1483, 1487, 1489}, {1871, 1873, 1877, 1879}, {2081, 2083, 2087, 2089}  and so on.

All these except {5,7,11,13} follow a general structure i.e, " **{ 30n+11  30n+13  30n+17  30n+19 }**" where 'n' is some integer.

(note: Not for all integer values, for example, If n=1, then quadruple={41,43,47,49} where 49 is not a prime number).

Reference: [Wikipage](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_quadruplet&ei=Vl1xU-neKIq1uAS4poGADw&usg=AFQjCNGzymENOFjp5Hn0GEKKSSBoRjrwCg&sig2=YlGFQBLcV38uCVBNhb46CA&bvm=bv.66330100,d.c2E)

---

**Algorithm for Prime Quadruples:**

Step 1: Generate quadruples by using the general format (given above in bold).

Step 2: Check if all the four values are prime numbers.

```
    Step 2a: if yes, then print the values as prime Quadruples.

    Step 2b: if no, discard the quadruples.
```

Step 3: Check if the fourth value generated by Step 1 is less than 999

```
    Step 3a: if yes, then go to step 1 and continue.

    Step 3b: if no, then exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use (y/10)%10 to see what the second digit is. Then you can compare for four in a row. From here, use @SJuan76 's answer to check the array of 4

Answer (score 0):

Using your existent program , you just need to substitute what happens when you find a prime.

Instead of printing it, I suggest you save the last prime found to a variable. Also keep three more variables for previously found primes. Then check is those variables are in the same range. If they are print them.

Something like

```
        if (PRIME) {
            //printf("\n%d", y);
            lastprime = y; // lastprime1 = lastprime2 = lastprime3 = 0;
            if (samerange(lastprime, lastprime1, lastprime2, lastprime3)) {
                // print them
            }
        }
```

Comment: ... of course, when you find a prime, you need to rotate the `lastprime` variables.